# Why won't node.js work for me across any of my applications? ELIFECYCLE error

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Every application I run gets the same error message: ELIFECYCLE**

Here is my error message:

```js
> pwd@1.0.0 start /Users/test/Desktop/test
> server.js

sh: server.js: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! pwd@1.0.0 start: `server.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pwd@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/test/.npm/_logs/2020-08-22T14_40_02_505Z-debug.log
Andrews-iMac:test test$
```

[image]

I threw up this super basic application to test whether it was happening across all of my projects. Clearly it is. Any ideas as to how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your package.json, I noticed your start script only has “server.js” in it. You might have to write

```
“start”: “node server.js”
```

As your start script in order for it to work

Answer (score 2):

Your `start` script needs to indicate you want to run `node`, it's not implied, since technically you can run any command in there

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try editing your start script to be

```
node server.js
```

Or even just run this command on your terminal.

This is how you use node.js to create a runtime environment for your js file